# How to use apply to send data from one dataframe to another

Tags: r

I am having some trouble in using an apply loop to extract data from one dataframe and send it to to another. I was wondering if anyone might be able to offer some guidance?

I essentially have two data frames each containing geographical data each at a different resolution. One set at the finer "LSOA" resolution, and some at the coarser "MSOA" resolution. Each MSOA has a unique ID, and contains a set number of LSOAs with unique IDs. I'm trying to design a function to make a data frame at LSOA resolution, containing the data originally at that resolution, alongside the coarser MSOA data (represented by dividing data at the MSOA level by the number of LSOAs in that MSOA).

My MSOA level data is in a dataframe "MSOA_data", and my LSOA level data in a dataframe "LSOA_data", and I've designed a function, MSOA_to_LSOAs(x), which returns a list of LSOAs in the given MSOA. I had hoped the following code would achieve this, looping over all rows in the MSOA data and transferring data to a relevant empty column in LSOA_data, but it doesn't seem to be working as I'd expected.

```
apply(MSOA_data, 1, function(x) {
    MSOA_ID <- x[1]
    MSOA_kWh <- as.numeric(x[2])
    LSOAs=as.vector(MSOA_to_LSOAs(MSOA_ID))
    N_LSOAs <- length(LSOAs)
    LSOA_kWh <- MSOA_kWh/N_LSOAs
    lapply (LSOAs, function(y) {
        LSOA_data$LSOA_kWh[which(LSOA_data$LSOA==y)] <- LSOA_kWh
    })
})
```

Both loops run, but there is no change to the "LSOA_data" data frame afterwards, and the "lapply" run seems to run for each set of LSOAs, but then to run again, seemingly with no data...

I was wondering if anyone might have some advice about how to achieve this? (or if I'm going about it completely the wrong way).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share some data - just a few rows - of sample input and desired output.

Comment: Why not just merge the two datasets and then keep needed columns?

Comment: I think you will need somehting like merging:

`merge(MSOA_data, LSOA_data, by = "ID", all = TRUE) `

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I figured out my critical problem was that I needed to replace the "<-" with a "<<-" in the lapply loop to write to the global rather than local dataframe, and the code seems to be working now. I think the "merge" function could be a more elegant way of achieving a part of what I wanted to here though.